# x, y, z coordinates of an object for a nwc file in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to find x,y,z coordinates of an object inside nwc model, and I am using below code.

Despite that this code was working for rvt files, it is not working for nwc model.

Is there a way to get x,y,z coordinates from a nwc model?

```
getFragmentWorldMatrixByNodeId(nodeId) {
        let result = {
            fragId: [],
            matrix: [],
        };
        let viewer = this.viewer;
        this.tree.enumNodeFragments(nodeId, function (frag) {

            let fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, frag);
            let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

            fragProxy.getWorldMatrix(matrix);

            result.fragId.push(frag);
            result.matrix.push(matrix);
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are looking for the "x,y,z coordinates of an object". What exactly do you mean by that? I'm going to assume that you want the coordinates of the **center point** of the object's bounding box, as that is what people ask for usually. In your code snippet, however, you're retrieving the entire transformation matrix, not a position.

If the center point of a bounding box works for you, you could obtain it like so:

```js
function getObjectBoundingBox(model, dbid) {
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    let totalBounds = new THREE.Box3();
    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragid) {
        let fragBounds = new THREE.Box3();
        frags.getWorldBounds(fragid, fragBounds);
        totalBounds.union(fragBounds);
    }, true);
    return totalBounds;
}

getObjectBoundingBox(viewer.model, 123).center();
```